# Grails Spring Security skip password check for dev

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails Spring Security plugin version:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
compile ":spring-security-acl:2.0-RC2"
```

is it possible to turn off password check somehow for my dev environment?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is diable security in the development environment, you can do this by adding this line in your `development` section of your grails configuration (depending on your version of grails, here Config.groovy, for grails 2.x):

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = false
    }
}
```

In grails 3, you can do this in application.yml

```
environments:
    development:
        grails:
            plugin:
                springsecurity:
                    active: false
```

Comment: so will it allow me to login without password?

Comment: It will not log you in, it will disable spring security. If you want to log in without password, and still have some kind of security roles other than anonymous, this will not help.